# Timer not getting repeated

Tags: iphone, ios

My timer not getting repeated please help

here is the code

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

method

```
-(void)doAnimation:(id)Sender
{
}
```

Comment: are you invalidating the timer anywhere?

Comment: no i have write only the above code

Comment: just use [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES], no fire.

Comment: @ aleph_null then it does not called even single time :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[timer fire]` manually fires the timer *only once* and is not actually "starting" the timer. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire):

> You can use this method to fire a repeating timer without interrupting its regular firing schedule. If the timer is non-repeating, it is automatically invalidated after firing, even if its scheduled fire date has not arrived.

You need to [add the timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) in a run loop before it will start firing and repeating:

> You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:. Then, after seconds seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, sending the message aSelector to target. (If the timer is configured to repeat, there is no need to subsequently re-add the timer to the run loop.)

An easier way would be to do something like:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and:

```
-(void)doAnimation:(NSTimer*)timer
{
}
```

This [automatically schedules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a) the timer and adds it to the run loop. Just in case you aren't doing it, as you have set the target to be `self` you have to make sure the method `doAnimation` is defined within the same class.

[NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: then how to start timer any other method then run loop

Comment: Great :) Don't forget to mark as an answer so others know what to do when they come across the same problem.

Comment: This is the way to do it. In Swift it looks like this:         NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(flashTime, target: self, selector: "fire:", userInfo: 0, repeats: true)

Answer (score 3):

using timerWithTimeInterval requires you to attach it to a run loop.  Try using

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target self selector:@selector(doAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

change your doAnimation method to the following:

```
-(void)doAnimation:(NSTimer *)timer{
         // do Something
}
```

p.s why are you telling it to fire immediately?  I don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, given the details, is that you are adding the timer to a run loop on a thread which exits before 1 second has elapsed.

Example: You create the timer on a secondary thread, the timer is destroyed when the secondary thread exits.

When a thread dies, its run loop dies, when its run loop dies, its timers are invalidated.

If this is the case, one easy way around this is to add it to the main run loop.

In some cases, you will (of course) want the timer on a specific run loop or thread, but this misunderstanding has caused similar problems for people in the past.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, saved my life :) I was having a problem with the "reset" timer. It was removed from the main run loop when invalidated, and after restarting it, it was added to a secondary run loop which was not persistent.